# Turning a div into a link makes more than the div a link

Tags: html, css

When I try to turn a div into a link, all of the area to the right of the div also becomes a div. The div displays as a block and has a fixed width. When I make the div linkable, the white space to the right of the div becomes linked, too. I thought that making the div a block and fixing its width would make only the area inside of the div linkable.

Comment: do you have any code we can look at?

Comment: What's your problem? This is vague...

Comment: we need to have look to resolve your problem

Comment: Usually Purple is the answer that solves most problems! Or, you could post some css, html or link on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3):

Without having any code to look at, I would imagine the problem is that you have it set as a block. By definition the block attribute makes the tag it is acting on display the entire width of the parent container. Try changing it to display:inline instead.